# Android kill service when app relauch and close?

Tags: android, service, kill

I have to run a task in background when reach the scheduled time.i assigned the task of waking up my service to `Alarm Manager` and it does well if the app is background/running.service keep running fine on app's background as well as foreground states if am not changing the state of app after beginning the service.for the purpose of well understanding the scenario's given below.

**Case 1:**

> 1.Setting up the schedule and sending the time to alarm manager and keep the app running.
>
> 2.Alarm manager calls the service when the time is reaching.
>
> 3.Service start running
>
> 4.when i close my app service get stopped

**Case 2:**

> 1.Setting up the schedule and sending the time to alarm manager and closing the app.now app in background.
>
> 2.Alarm manager calls the service when the time is reaching.
>
> 3.Service start running
>
> 4.Relaunching the app.service continuing running/working fine.
>
> 5.Now closing the app and the result is service dead.

I have to call the service only by `Alarm Manager` , not on every time when app launches for that purpose in service `onStartCommand` method i returned `START_NOT_STICKY` and i don't want to use `START_STICKY`.if i goes to `START_STICKY` it won't consider the scheduled time.and the thing is i don't want to check the time again as it's doing well by `Alarm Manager`.

When app running on low memory the services get destroyed.is the solution using startForeground instead of startService ?

How can i make my service running stable without bothering about the app opening/closing states ?

> **Setting schedule**

```
public void setAction(View v) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(HH.getText().toString());
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(MM.getText().toString());
        int second = Integer.parseInt(SS.getText().toString());
        String peried = PP.getText().toString();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, peried.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") ? Calendar.AM : Calendar.PM);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
        myIntent.putExtra(ACTION,
                ACTION_SC_1);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE_SC_1, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

> **Service class**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
   

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            final String action = intent.getStringExtra(ACTION);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Timer timer = new Timer();
            final TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Toast.makeText(MyAlarmService.this, "Running....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 1000, 5000); //execute in every 5000 msdo

          //  this.stopSelf();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           //TODO
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Killed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Anywhere in your activity you are calling stopService() mthod?

Comment: never, i checked the possible cases like that :)

Comment: START_STICKY will restart the service being stopped by OS immediately and START_REDELIVER_INTENT will slow down the restart operation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to avoid killing of service...but we can not guarantee it. In low memory situations the service will be killed by the os. At this situation if you return `START_STICKY` this will restart the service with null intent. If you want the intent to be not null return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`
See the android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT)

Comment: As this will create a new copy of our app.Is it a efficient way ?

Comment: The service will run in the separate process...Ya this is the recommended way to avoid killing the service.

Comment: What about the usage of memory?

Comment: The memory usage will not get effected while running in the separate process.

Comment: But i think popular app's like facebook running their service in main process only.how it can be ?

Comment: How can you say that facebook service is not running on the separate process??

Comment: Take a look at the phone application manager.it's showing the running service of FB using main process.

Comment: May be you are right...it depends on their requirement...They may returning START_STICKY from onStartCommand() so that their service will restart if it is destroyed in low memory situations.